# Techniques To Reduce Build Time On Heavy Swift - ObjC Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, legacy

I am working on large project which contain 300 swift files, 1500 Objective C files (.h, .m), 500 .xib files, many target checks in code.
Build process takes **8** minutes i could only managed to analyze swift classes build times (not all of them) and it seems that its not the problem.
Which parts of my project could be tweaked in order to improve build times?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you thought about splitting your code (if possible) into modules and include them by some kind of dependency manager e.g. Cocoapods?

Comment: this project started 6 years ago and in the next year we will build the next gen from scratch. so im looking for a way to optimize it

Comment: Are you using cocoapods? If yes, how many? If cocoapods and more than 10 then moving to Carthage will fix the issue. The trick is to use dependencies as frameworks. Even if this does not improve to the desired amount of time then break your code into modules and create frameworks of those modules and use those modules as frameworks.

Comment: Hi @Kamran no dependency manager at all

Comment: Ok then you can break your code into modules and use them as frameworks.

Comment: thats an option for sure but im looking for tweaks that will be easy to change like build settings etc

Comment: Buy a nvme ssd or m.2 ?:) same problem with internal drive from iMac ... faster was  after trying even a ssd linked to USB 2.0, 3.0 (1) ports ...